# Capture console output of called application in calling batch file

Tags: batch-file, logging, scripting

I have a batch file which launches let's say 10 applications one after the other.

It waits till the launched application finishes and then proceeds to next one. There is no problem here.

However I am unable to capture (in the batch file) the console output which each of the 10 called applications produce.

Below is what I am talking about:

```
start /wait ./TestApp1/Debug/TestApp1.exe
start /wait ./TestApp2/Debug/TestApp2.exe
start /wait ./TestApp3/Debug/TestApp3.exe
start /wait ./TestApp4/Debug/TestApp4.exe
start /wait ./TestApp5/Debug/TestApp5.exe
start /wait ./TestApp6/Debug/TestApp6.exe
start /wait ./TestApp7/Debug/TestApp7.exe
start /wait ./TestApp8/Debug/TestApp8.exe
start /wait ./TestApp9/Debug/TestApp9.exe
start /wait ./TestApp10/Debug/TestApp10.exe
```

Lets say each of the TestApp generate some output.
I want to consolidate all of them into one text file.
Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Surround the entire execution with (parentheses) and then use redirection to capture the output to a file.   `(all your exeecutables)>logfile.txt`

Comment: @Squashman do you mean this way?


`(start /wait ./TestApp1/Debug/TestApp1.exe
start /wait ./TestApp2/Debug/TestApp2.exe
start /wait ./TestApp3/Debug/TestApp3.exe
start /wait ./TestApp4/Debug/TestApp4.exe
start /wait ./TestApp5/Debug/TestApp5.exe
start /wait ./TestApp6/Debug/TestApp6.exe
start /wait ./TestApp7/Debug/TestApp7.exe
start /wait ./TestApp8/Debug/TestApp8.exe
start /wait ./TestApp9/Debug/TestApp9.exe
start /wait ./TestApp10/Debug/TestApp10.exe) > logfile.txt?`

Comment: From cmd.exe or another batch file, you could use `Call "M:\yBatch\file.cmd">"logfile.txt"`, if you want any errors included too, change that to `Call "M:\yBatch\file.cmd">"logfile.txt" 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you first of all try it without the `Start` command:

```batch-file
@(
    "TestApp1\Debug\TestApp1.exe"
    "TestApp2\Debug\TestApp2.exe"
    "TestApp3\Debug\TestApp3.exe"
    "TestApp4\Debug\TestApp4.exe"
    "TestApp5\Debug\TestApp5.exe"
    "TestApp6\Debug\TestApp6.exe"
    "TestApp7\Debug\TestApp7.exe"
    "TestApp8\Debug\TestApp8.exe"
    "TestApp9\Debug\TestApp9.exe"
    "TestApp10\Debug\TestApp10.exe"
) > "logfile.txt"
```

If you really do need that `Start` command, then similarly:

```batch-file
@(
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp1\Debug\TestApp1.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp2\Debug\TestApp2.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp3\Debug\TestApp3.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp4\Debug\TestApp4.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp5\Debug\TestApp5.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp6\Debug\TestApp6.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp7\Debug\TestApp7.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp8\Debug\TestApp8.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp9\Debug\TestApp9.exe"
    Start "" /Wait "TestApp10\Debug\TestApp10.exe"
) > "logfile.txt"
```

If your application requires the use of `Start`, then you would be well advised to take a look at its usage information, *(options such as `/B` may also be needed)*.

*Please note, that I've included doublequotes, such that the script can be used as a template for others, without worrying about problematic characters, and I've also used the correct path separators for Windows, i.e. the back slash.*